# Does anyone know of a way to globally scope ActiveRecord? I'm looking to achieve a snapshot in time of my entire database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord

At work, I often need to investigate data in a previous state. For example, a user was seeing time-sensitive information in their app 3 days ago (their last 50 order records). That information has since been overridden by newer orders. In order to replicate that issue for debugging, I need to limit all pertinent data (orders, user interactions, etc.) before a certain timestamp.

My question boils down to this: Instead of scoping each table that I'm querying (and risk missing something), is there a clean way to scope all timestamps on records and tables that might be queried during this kind of investigation?

I'm on Rails 5.1.6

Comment: Monkeypatch [`#default_scope`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Default/ClassMethods.html#method-i-default_scope)?

Comment: This sounds more like you need to take regular backups of the table (which is done with the DB specific tools) or use something like Papertrail which lets you track changes to records by creating copies.

Comment: You can also use the [Timecop gem](https://github.com/travisjeffery/timecop) to "mock time".

Answer (score 0):

interesting question.

If I were in your shoes, I'd investigate whether I could achieve what you're looking to do using database views (assuming your using Postgres). Especially sense it sounds like you are looking to do lookups on multiple tables that may or may not be related.

Check out this gem: https://github.com/scenic-views/scenic to get an idea of how you could implement views, though you don't necessarily need a gem.

That said, why I think this would be good for you is because it would allow you to set up a filter for the data you want, which then you could filter accordingly, and then just make some test to validate accuracy.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a job for ARel.  ARel makes it a lot easier to build time/system clock based Scopes.  You can define as many of these as you want.

```
ARel:

scope :created_at_before, ->(timestamp) { where( arel_table[:created_at].gte(timestamp) }
scope :created_at_over_three_months_ago, { created_at_before(3.months.ago) }
#and so on and so on...
```

But I have to ask this....

You want a "snapshot in time of your database".

**Take a backup?????**  A backup of your database **is** a snapshot in time of your database.  Restore this backup on a separate machine.  You can even automate taking these backups with `cron`, Heroku Scheduler, or your platforms equivalent.